# how to avoid a nested loop

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, nested-loops

I am trying to achieve the following

```
public class MyObject {
    Map<String, String> myMap;
}

public class MyOtherObject {
    List<MyObject> myObjects;
}
```

I want to be able to do the following

```
for (MyObject myObject: myObjects) {
    Map<String,String> newMap = new Hashmap<String,String>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myObject.getMyMap.entrySet() {
        newMap.put(entry.key + "a" , entry.value)
    }
}
```

How do I avoid this nested loop?

Comment: are you running that on a java8 env.???

Comment: no java 7, but I would be curious about the java 8 solution

Comment: BTW, move the `Map<String,String> newMap = new Hashmap<String,String>();` outside for loop. You are creating a new map each time !

Comment: You can't avoid the nested loop. However you achieve this, every key in every map has to be touched, so you can't reduce the complexity. If you just hate nests though, you can move the nest loop into a private utility function. Your only other option is to code MyOtherObject to do the transform on insert so that you never have to change the keys in the first place.

Comment: It's not clear if you want to create a new map for every object of the list, or if you want one single map that contains all the entries of the inner maps with their key modified

Answer (score 3):

- Regarding your current solution, you'll need to move the `newMap`
  declaration outside the loop otherwise you're creating a new map at each iteration of the loop and that would not contain the result you'd expect.
- You also have a typo on your map instantiation, change `Hashmap` to
  `HashMap`.

---

As for avoiding nested loops, you can create a stream instance of the `entrySet` then simply perform a reduction operation on the stream using `collect`.

```
Map<String, String> copy = myObject.getMyMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey() + "a", Map.Entry::getValue));
```

if you want to copy all of the mappings from the specified map to another map then as `svasa` has suggested within the comments, you can do:

```
newMap.putAll(myObject.getMyMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey() + "a", Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide explanation on how it works, and also how the `newMap` could be populated like `newMap.putAll( myObject.getMyMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey() + "a", Map.Entry::getValue)));` Another note is user also needs to move the `Map<String,String> newMap = new Hashmap<String,String>();` above for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `putAll`:

```
Amap.putAll(Bmap);
```

Comment: Nice, but I want to modify the key before putting it into the map

Answer (score 0):

The complexity will always be `O(n x m)`, with `n` being the size of the list and `m` the maximum size of the inner maps.

With java 8, you can use:

```
Map<String, String> result = myObjects.stream()
    .flatMap(myObject -> myObject.getMyMap().entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey() + "a", Entry::getValue));
```

This assumes you want only one map with all the entries of all the inner maps, with their key modified.

I've used [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to flatten all the streams with the entries of the inner maps into one stream. Then, I've used [`Collectors.toMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) to collect all these entries into a new map.

This will fail if there are repeated keys. In such case, you can use the [overloaded version of `Collectors.toMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), which accepts a function to merge values when there's a collision between keys:

```
Map<String, String> result = myObjects.stream()
    .flatMap(myObject -> myObject.getMyMap().entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey() + "a", Entry::getValue, String::concat));
```

This simply concatenates the values that are mapped more than once to the same key, but you can use any other merge function.

Comment: what is the complexity of this